# $u$-substitute in integration

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

So the $u$-substitute theorem states that $$\int f(g(x))g’(x)~dx = \int f(u)~du$$
But when we use the $u$-substitution, we say $u=g(x)$ right?
So my question is why when we use this we can change $u$ and then take derivative.
For example, if we do $u=3x^2-1$ than we can write $x^2=(u+1)/3$
And only then take derivatives from both sides? Plus what operation can we do before taking derivatives from both sides? How does it stands with the theorem?

Comment: I am having a hard time parsing this question. Are you asking why this works?

Comment: Yes thats what i am asking why can u change the function of the theorem before taking derivative?

Answer (score 0):

the first part is right indeed let $u = g(x)$ so
$$\frac{du}{dx} = g'(x)\implies du = g'(x)dx$$

And we can easily write
$$\int f(g(x))g'(x)dx= \int f(u)du$$

You can check also on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) I think it's explained very well - at least for me :) -

The second part is trying to reverse the process. Taking your example let $u=g(x)=3x^2-1$ so we have
$$du = 6xdx\\
\frac{du}{6x} = dx $$
And what is $x$ in term of $u$? The inversion above so
$$x= \pm\sqrt{\frac{u+1}{3}}$$
Here is where we need to be a little careful because the function we substitute has to be continuous. For the sake of simplicity I'll go with $+$ and
$$dx= \frac{1}{6}\cdot \bigg(\frac{u+1}{3}\bigg)^{-1/2}du$$

and is exactly what we write above in terms of $u$. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ty very much for ur time But i am asking why u can do the part where divide by 6 and get du/6x=dx

Comment: Expressions like $du=g'dx$ aren't the best way to convince someone substitution works, as derivatives aren't fractions. It's more to the point that the chain rule proves$$\frac{d}{dx}\int f(u)du=g'(x)f(g(x))$$for any choice of the antiderivative $\int f(u)du$.

Comment: @J.G. more concise, absolutely better than my explanation.